# Synchronize scroll between UITableView and UICollectionView : lag when using multiple scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a view with a collectionView (single horizontal line) and a tableview below. Both view are synced while scrolling since they display the same data in different manners. In fact, it's like the "fantastical" app if you have this app.

I managed to sync both views using UIScrollView Delegate methods

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll %@ - %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset), NSStringFromCGPoint(self.previousScrollOffset));
    switch (self.scrollAnimation) {
        case ScrollAnimationFromCollection:
        {
            if (currentOffset.x > self.previousScrollOffset.x && (self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionLeft || self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionNone))
            {
                // NSLog(@"Change to Right!");
                self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionRight;
                [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
            }
            else if (currentOffset.x <= self.previousScrollOffset.x && (self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionRight || self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionNone))
            {
                // NSLog(@"Change to Left!");
                self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionLeft;
                [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
            }
            [self moveTableView];
            break;
        }

        case ScrollAnimationFromTableView:
        {
            if (currentOffset.y - self.previousScrollOffset.y > 0 && self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionBottom)
            {
                self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionTop;
                [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
            }
            else if (currentOffset.y - self.previousScrollOffset.y <= 0 && self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionTop)
            {
                self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionBottom;
                [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
            }
            [self moveCollectionView];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
    self.previousScrollOffset = currentOffset;
}

#pragma mark - Move actions
- (void)moveCollectionView
{
    NSIndexPath* currentIp = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"currentIp %@", currentIp);
    if (![self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths containsObject:currentIp])
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll to IndexPath centered!");
        [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths addObject:currentIp];
        [self.collectionViewController.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:currentIp atScrollPosition:PSTCollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)moveTableView
{
    NSIndexPath* currentIp = [self.collectionViewController.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.horizontalContainer convertPoint:self.horizontalContainer.center toView:self.collectionViewController.collectionView]];
    NSLog(@"currentIp %@", currentIp);
    if (![self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths containsObject:currentIp])
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll to IndexPath At Top!");
        [self.alreadySelectedIndexPaths addObject:currentIp];
        self.tableView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:currentIp atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

It works pretty great except for one thing : when I scroll the collectionview, the tableview takes some time to scroll due to the animated (YES) parameter. If I use scrollToRowAtIndexPath: with no animation, it works like a charm. But as soon as I use the animation flag, it seems (quite logically) that iOS queue the scrollToRowAtIndexPath and run them once at a time, resulting in a lag in the animation.

FWI, the alreadySelectedIndexPaths contains a list of indexPath to which I already scrolled (I don't know if this sentence is quite clear though :D :D)

I looked if there was a way to cancel the previous order, but apart from cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: with cancels the last performSelector call, it didn't find anything useful.

Do you seen how can I manage to get a smooth animation here?

Thnaks for your help.

Comment: Why are the scroll view delegates not being called? This is very easy to do by using them.

Comment: The delegate are beeing called, but not continuously. 
It seems that the scrollViewDidScroll is called only once when the user scrolls with his finger, but not after that.
There is also the scrollViewWillEndDragging: that could be used since there is a targetOffset, but it would be a little tricky to calculate the deceleration of each views :-/

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is called repeatedly during any movement of the scroll view. It gets called whether the user is scrolling or it is decelerating.

Comment: @Khal When you say 'sync' I understand both tableview and collectionview will scroll at the same time. However `switch` case in your code in `updateUIFromTimer:` method suggests otherwise. Why not remove the switch and call update on both table and collection? Additionally both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` inherit from `UIScrollView`, so you can programmatically scroll both using `setContentOffset:animated:` method (with or without animation).

Comment: @Fogmeister : that's the thing, it is not called continuously, only when the scroll starts. After that, it is no longer called. Very hard to know when the scroll really stop either :-/

Comment: @Amar : I have to use a switch because when the user scrolls one view, I don't want to make this view scroll, only the other one ;)

Comment: @Fogmeister : I checked with a simple project with a tableview, the scrollviewdidscroll is called continuously indeed. But it is not in my app, very weird... I'll check it out...

Comment: Heh, good work checking it out. You saved me the time of doing it. I was beginning to doubt myself. :D

Comment: @Fogmeister : lol my bad. I still have the same issue, but the code is clearer :D

Comment: Don't animate the scroll of the tableView. Because it is happening so often you don't need to animate the scrolling. Don't use the `scrollTo...` method. Just set the scroll offset. You'll have to calculate the offset yourself but just convert the x offset of the collectionView to a y offset in the tableView.

Comment: @Fogmeister : I was thinking of that but I was too lazy to try it :D
When calculating the offset, I just animate it inside a [UIView animateWithDuration:...] ?
I'll try it out right now and let you know ;) Thanks.

Comment: My bad : setContentOffset:animated will work just fine :D

Comment: @Fogmeister : it tried a very simple code, but I still have the same issue : animating the contentOffset result in a lag. I get the same behavior as using scrollToRowAtIndexPath.
I don't think that I can use gcd either since all the UI changes have to made on the main thread right?

Comment: Don't animate it. Just set it. It's being run so many times that you don't need to animate it.

Comment: @Fogmeister : it works like a charm! Please post for answer so that I could vote for it and thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the scrollviewDidScroll method whenever the tableView or collectionView is scrolled.

In here you can take the offset of the view being scrolled and convert this into an offset for the other view.

Then you can just set this offset on the other view.

You don't need to animate to the offset or anything as the delegate method gets called within the animation loop anyway so just setting the offset will make it look like both views are being animated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :-D

Comment: Hey buddy! We tried to do this but seems like the offset we are using (from the collectionView) is not synced when applying it to the scroll view, do you have any idea if some kind of conversion needed?

Comment: @RoiMulia You shouldn’t do. What do you mean not synced? The collection view IS a scroll view. So the content offset will be the same. What differences are you seeing? Maybe an idea to add a new question with your code etc... then link it. I’ll take a look :-)

Comment: I'll try to tackle this with my team. If we won't succeed I'll post a question! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. What worked form me was the following:

1. Create a custom subclasses of UITableView and UICollectionView
2. Both of those subclasses should conform to `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate
3. In both of those classes override the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` method

```swift
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

4. Your table view and collection view need to have the same superview. Add both gesture recognizers to your superview

```swift
yourSuperview.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
yourSuperview.addGestureRecognizer(tableView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

Hope this helps!